# how to add values from a textfield to a jcombobox in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, combobox, jbutton

hi I am using java eclipse with Swing UI for my school project and I am having trouble trying to add inputted values form a textfield to a combobox whether it is by the user pressing enter or a button.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @kennyy: I downvoted/VTC because [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)
and [no research was done](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and [a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) was not included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a button:

```
JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
```

To make the button do something when you click on it, you implement an ActionListener:

```
okButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Now you want to read the text from the input field:

```
JTextField userInput = new JTextField();
```

and add it to the Combobox:

```
JComboBox myComboBox = new JComboBox();
```

maybe you already have some items in your combobox like this:

```
myComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "First Item" }));
```

Anyhow - to read the input and add it to the combobox, all you have to do in your ActionListener method is this:

```
String userInputText = userInput.getText();  // read the text from the JTextInput
myComboBox.addItem(userInputText);   // add it as a new Item to the combobox
```

**EDIT**

Here is *one* way of putting it all together. It has nothing to do with Eclipse or any other IDE you could use. It's just Java - and you'll find other/better ways of putting it all together, the more you learn about Java. Hope this helps you to get started:

```
public class MyProgram extends JFrame {
    // here you declare your global variables
    private JTextInput userInput;
    private JButton okButton;
    private JComboBox myComboBox;    

    public MyProgram () {
        // here you create your objects
        okButton = new JButton("OK");
        myComboBox = new JComboBox<>();
        userInput = new JTextField();

        // then you initialize them
        myComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "First Item" }));

        okButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                 // and that is the code that gets executed once the user clicks the button
                 String userInputText = userInput.getText(); 
                 myComboBox.addItem(userInputText);   
            }
        });
    }

    // this is what Eclipse will propably generate for you so you can launch the program and show your frame:
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyProgram().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do it when you initialize your JFrame. Right after you created your button you can put the code with `okButton.addActionListener....` . Then you replace the comment `// do stuff` with the code you want to execute when the button is clicked.

Comment: after doing this I am left with the error myComboBox cannot be resolved

Comment: It's easier to make all GUI objects global. Your surrounding JFrame object will be there anyway, so there is no harm in having your buttons and comboboxes global. So, `private JComboBox myComboBox;` and when you initialize it use `this.myComboBox = new JComboBox();`. Then you can resolve it from within the actionListener as well.

Comment: I am sorry but I am very new to eclipse and what do u mean by initialize and the private jcombobox where would I put these

Comment: I edited my answer and provided a full example. Hope this helps to get an idea.